# Change X and Y value of SVG elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tspan element and I want it to move based on mouse position.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  //something that makes it so the x value is the same as e.pageX
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1778.426 150.81301">
<g transform="translate(0 -146.19)">
<rect x="15.368" y="225.71" width="1723.8" height="11.733"/>
<rect id="bar" transform="rotate(90)" x="215.19" y="-15.368" width="32.781" height="11.733"/>
</svg>
```

How can I do it without using transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the attribute of it directly with `attr()`, for instance...

```
<script>
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  //something that makes it so the x value is the same as e.pageX
    $('#bar').attr('x', e.pageX);
});
</script>
```

I have put together a small demo sandbox at JSBIN: [JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/kikohiv/1/edit?html,output).

You may need to tweak this a bit further, but I am seeing some movement of the #bar element in document mousemove events.